# How to get data from all pages in Github API with Python?

Tags: python, api, github, pagination, python-requests

I'm trying to export a repo list and it always returns me information about the 1rst page. I could extend the number of items per page using URL+"?per_page=100" but it's not enough to get the whole list.
I need to know how can I get the list extracting data from page 1, 2,...,N.
I'm using Requests module, like this:

```
while i <= 2:
      r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/xxxxxxx/repos?page{0}&per_page=100'.format(i), auth=('My_user', 'My_passwd'))
      repo = r.json()
      j = 0
      while j < len(repo):
            print repo[j][u'full_name']
            j = j+1
      i = i + 1
```

I use that while condition 'cause I know there are 2 pages, and I try to increase it in that waym but It doesn't work

Comment: print the `url` generated in each iteration and check whether it is correct or not

Comment: You have the line: `repo=p.json()` Is this a typo? Should it read `r.json()`?

Answer (score 44):

```
import requests

url = "https://api.github.com/XXXX?simple=yes&per_page=100&page=1"
res=requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization": git_token})
repos=res.json()
while 'next' in res.links.keys():
  res=requests.get(res.links['next']['url'],headers={"Authorization": git_token})
  repos.extend(res.json())
```

If you aren't making a full blown app use a "Personal Access Token"

> https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a response.links attribute. This answer needs to be selected as best answer. Every other solution is a hack!

Answer (score 6):

From [github docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories):

Response:

```
Status: 200 OK
Link: <https://api.github.com/resource?page=2>; rel="next",
      <https://api.github.com/resource?page=5>; rel="last"
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
```

You get the links to the next and the last page of that organization. Just check the headers.

On Python Requests, you can access your headers with:

```
response.headers
```

It is a dictionary containing the response headers. If **link** is present, then there are more pages and it will contain related information. It is recommended to traverse using those links instead of building your own.

You can try something like this:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/xxxxxxx/repos?page{0}&per_page=100'
response = requests.get(url)
link = response.headers.get('link', None)
if link is not None:
    print link
```

If link is not None it will be a string containing the relevant links for your resource.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already found that on github docs and I have no idea about how it works. I couldn't find the way to implement it using python. Can you help me please?

Comment: Yeah, i am checking that at the moment. Do you have an org with a lot of pages?

Comment: I'm a beginner using APIs and Python, I really appreciate your help. I've an organization with 44 users and 190 repos, so it's imposible to download them all in one shot beacuse of the max is 100 items.

Comment: Just check if the headers dict contains the key link, in which case you can find the next one to request and do that until it doesn't show up.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can I contact you in order to learn something? I think I will be really quick by chatting

Comment: I get the link but I have read-only permissions because of my reputation. If you want, you can chat me another way to contact us, I'm reading

Comment: I will edit the question with some more details then i guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I could get the pagination info but I have no idea about how to scroll through the pages in order to print them all. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You will have to request them all. You can just request everything until you hit the last one and concatenate them.

Comment: I understand, but I wanna do it using "while" and I just can't do it. I tried a lot of ways and all what I get is an error message.

Comment: I'm not sure how t do that either.
I'm going to figure it out for javascript..

In the meantime, here is something written in ruby, that may be of help:
https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/api/ruby/traversing-with-pagination/changing_number_of_items.rb

Perhaps looking at that snippet will put you on the right path to the python solution..

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, link will be None if only a single page of data is returned, otherwise link will be present even when going beyond the last page. In this case link will contain previous and first links.

Here is some sample python which aims to simply return the link for the next page, and returns None if there is no next page. So could incorporate in a loop.

```
link = r.headers['link']
if link is None:
    return None

# Should be a comma separated string of links
links = link.split(',')

for link in links:
    # If there is a 'next' link return the URL between the angle brackets, or None
    if 'rel="next"' in link:
        return link[link.find("<")+1:link.find(">")]
return None
```

Comment: Helps if the accepted answer was tested better. This solves the two different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the answers above, here is a recursive function to deal with the GitHub pagination that will iterate through all pages, concatenating the list with each recursive call and finally returning the complete list when there are no more pages to retrieve, unless the optional failsafe returns the list when there are more than 500 items.

```
import requests

api_get_users = 'https://api.github.com/users'


def call_api(apicall, **kwargs):

    data = kwargs.get('page', [])

    resp = requests.get(apicall)
    data += resp.json()

    # failsafe
    if len(data) > 500:
        return (data)

    if 'next' in resp.links.keys():
        return (call_api(resp.links['next']['url'], page=data))

    return (data)


data = call_api(api_get_users)
```

Comment: That would be more nice if it'd be adapted to something like: `data = call_api(...); while data: # do something with the data; data = call_api(...)`. Basically to have some sort of iterator which allows you to retrieve data in batches, one page at a time :)

Answer (score 2):

First you use

```
print(a.headers.get('link'))
```

this will give you the number of pages the repository has, similar to below

```
<https://api.github.com/organizations/xxxx/repos?page=2&type=all>; rel="next", 

<https://api.github.com/organizations/xxxx/repos?page=8&type=all>; rel="last"
```

from this you can see that currently we are on first page of repo, rel='next' says that the next page is 2, and rel='last' tells us that your last page is 8.

After knowing the number of pages to traverse through,you just need to use '=' for page number while getting request and change the while loop until the last page number, not len(repo) as it will return you 100 each time.
for e.g

```
i=1
while i <= 8:
      r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/xxxx/repos?page={0}&type=all'.format(i),
                         auth=('My_user', 'My_passwd'))
      repo = r.json()
      for j in repo:
        print(repo[j][u'full_name'])
      i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        link = res.headers.get('link', None)

        if link is not None:
            link_next = [l for l in link.split(',') if 'rel="next"' in l]
            if len(link_next) > 0:
                return int(link_next[0][link_next[0].find("page=")+5:link_next[0].find(">")])
```