# How to get data from all pages in Git API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, git, api

I am trying to get a list of all repos within an organization. The Git api call only return 30 of the repos at a time. I know that this can be changed to a max 100 but my organization has more repos than that. I have the following code:

```js
async function getRepos() {
    const url = "THEURL"
    const headers = {
        "Authorization": `Token temppp`
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": headers
    })
    const result = await response.json()
    console.log(result)
    
    const temp = []
    result.items.forEach(i => {
        temp.push(i.name);
    })
    console.log(temp)

}
```

In this, I am trying to get the name of all repos, but I can only do 30 at a time. Does anyone know how can I get all of them or go through all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this in python, but I dont think this is efficient for making a large program. Especially because later on I will be working with git issues API in a similar way and each repo might have more than 1000 issues. -> [How to get data from all pages in Github API with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878019/how-to-get-data-from-all-pages-in-github-api-with-python)